# Why I cannot provide options for `git push` after a branch is tracked

Tags: git

Here is code:

```
$ git remote
origin

$ git commit -m ' add file001.cpp & file002.cpp'
[master ba23a26]  add file001.cpp & file002.cpp
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file001.cpp
 create mode 100644 file002.cpp

$ git branch -vv
* master              ba23a26 [origin/master: ahead 1]  add file001.cpp & file002.cpp
  develop 1c9a08c [origin/develop: ahead 1] add head file include

$ git push orgin master:master
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git push
...
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 285 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   92326c4..ba23a26  master -> master
```

Question> Why I cannot directly use the following command to push?

```
 $ git push orgin master:master
```

Thank you

Comment: You typed `orgin` instead of `origin`.  This is the origin (no pun intended) of your Git problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
git push orgin master:master
```

You intended to do this:

```
git push origin master:master
```

This tells Git to push a local branch called `master` to a remote branch which is also called `master`.  However, since you are already on the local `master` branch, you could use the abbreviated command:

```
git push origin master
```

This tells Git to push the current *local* branch (`master`) to a remote branch which is also called `master`.  Git will implicitly push whatever local branch on which you are.

Comment: You have enough rep that you should know what the close reasons are.  If the problem is caused by a typo, you should be voting to close it under the "cannot reproduce/problem caused by a typographical error" reason.

Comment: @cimmanon I was at first inclined to agree with you, but he also seems to have some confusion about the `git push` command itself, which I addressed.